# Проблема с получение данных с api.coinmarketcap android (Retrofit)

Tags: android, get, retrofit2

Работаю с Api Coinmarket, с помошью retrofit пытаюсь получить данные о крипте (для себя), данные не приходят (onFailure срабатывает), помогите пожалуйста, хотя ошибок по коду нет , все компилируется. (10 валют нужно)
Класс App.

```
    public class CApp extends Application {
private static CoinApi coinApi;
public Retrofit retrofit;

public void onCreate()
{
super.onCreate();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
coinApi = retrofit.create(CoinApi.class);
}

public static CoinApi getApi() {
return coinApi;
}
}
```

Интерфейс

```
    @GET("?limit=10")
    Call<List<Model>> messages();
```

Активити, где вызывается Retrofit:

```
CApp.getApi().messages().enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>>responsee) {
textView.setText(responsee.body().size() +" ");
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
textView.setText("Ошибка ");
}
});
```

---

На всякий случай модель скину

```
   @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("symbol")
@Expose
private String symbol;
@SerializedName("rank")
@Expose
private String rank;
@SerializedName("price_usd")
@Expose
private String priceUsd;
@SerializedName("price_btc")
@Expose
private String priceBtc;
@SerializedName("24h_volume_usd")
@Expose
private String _24hVolumeUsd;
@SerializedName("market_cap_usd")
@Expose
private String marketCapUsd;
@SerializedName("available_supply")
@Expose
private String availableSupply;
@SerializedName("total_supply")
@Expose
private String totalSupply;
@SerializedName("percent_change_1h")
@Expose
private String percentChange1h;
@SerializedName("percent_change_24h")
@Expose
private String percentChange24h;
@SerializedName("percent_change_7d")
@Expose
private String percentChange7d;
@SerializedName("last_updated")
@Expose
private String lastUpdated;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getSymbol() {
return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
this.symbol = symbol;
}

public String getRank() {
return rank;
}

public void setRank(String rank) {
this.rank = rank;
}

public String getPriceUsd() {
return priceUsd;
}

public void setPriceUsd(String priceUsd) {
this.priceUsd = priceUsd;
}

public String getPriceBtc() {
return priceBtc;
}

public void setPriceBtc(String priceBtc) {
this.priceBtc = priceBtc;
}

public String get24hVolumeUsd() {
return _24hVolumeUsd;
}

public void set24hVolumeUsd(String _24hVolumeUsd) {
this._24hVolumeUsd = _24hVolumeUsd;
}

public String getMarketCapUsd() {
return marketCapUsd;
}

public void setMarketCapUsd(String marketCapUsd) {
this.marketCapUsd = marketCapUsd;
}

public String getAvailableSupply() {
return availableSupply;
}

public void setAvailableSupply(String availableSupply) {
this.availableSupply = availableSupply;
}

public String getTotalSupply() {
return totalSupply;
}

public void setTotalSupply(String totalSupply) {
this.totalSupply = totalSupply;
}

public String getPercentChange1h() {
return percentChange1h;
}

public void setPercentChange1h(String percentChange1h) {
this.percentChange1h = percentChange1h;
}

public String getPercentChange24h() {
return percentChange24h;
}

public void setPercentChange24h(String percentChange24h) {
this.percentChange24h = percentChange24h;
}

public String getPercentChange7d() {
return percentChange7d;
}

public void setPercentChange7d(String percentChange7d) {
this.percentChange7d = percentChange7d;
}

public String getLastUpdated() {
return lastUpdated;
}

public void setLastUpdated(String lastUpdated) {
this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
}
```

Comment: Вот такая ошибка вылетает еще Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ , посмотрел в интернете и так и не понял как исправить

Answer (score 0):

1. Неправильно описан json, принимаемый от сервера. Во-первых, Вам приходит не список Model, а один объект, который видно, если свернуть json в парсере.
   [image: Сокращенный ответный json]

Вместо этого:

```
@GET("?limit=10")
Call<List<Model>> messages();
```

Нужно указать это:

```
@GET("?limit=10")
Call<TickerResponse> messages();
```

Где TickerResponse:

```
class TickerResponse{

    private ArrayList<Ticker> data;
    private Metadata metadata;

    public ArraList<Ticker> getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public Metadata getMetadata(){
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setData(ArraList<Ticker> data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata){
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

А класс metadata имеет следующий вид:

```
class Metadata{

    private long timestamp;
    @SerializedName("num_cryptocurrencies")
    private int numCryptocurrencies;
    private String error;

    public long getTimestamp(){
        return timestamp;
    }

    public getNumCryptocurrencies(){
        return numCryptocurrencies;
    }

    public String getError(){
        return error;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp){
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void setNumCryptocurrencies(int numCryptocurrencies){
        this.numCryptocurrencies = numCryptocurrencies;
    }

    public void setError(String error){
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

**Ticker** - описанная Вами модель

2. Просто так распарсить json не удастся, потому что он имеет нестандартный вид - имя элемента = его id. Поэтому необходимо написать дополнительный deserializer для данного запроса. Для этого нужно создать класс, который будет заниматься парсингом ответного json:

   ```
   public class TickersDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<TickerResponse> {

       @Override
       public TickerResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
           TickerResponse response = new TickerResponse();
           Gson gson = new Gson();
           Type tickerType = new TypeToken<Ticker>(){}.getType();
           Type metadataType = new TypeToken<Metadata>(){}.getType();

           JsonObject dataJson = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("data");
           ArraList<String> dataKeys = dataJson.getNames();
           ArraList<Ticker> tickerData = new ArrayList<>();
           for(String name: dataKeys){
               String ticker = dataJson.getAsJsonObject(name).toString();
               tickerData.add(gson.fromJson(ticker, tickerType));
           }

           JsonObject metadataJson = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("metadata");
           Metadata metadata = gson.fromJson(metadataJson.toString(), metadataType);

           response.setData(tickerData);
           response.setMetadata(metadata);
           return response;

       }
   }
   ```

Потом в классе App нужно прописать следующее:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(TickerResponse.class, new TickersDeserializer())
        .setLenient()
        .create();
```

И вместо *.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())* написать это: *.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder))*

После всех этих манипуляций должно заработать. Заранее извиняюсь, код писал в блокноте, могут быть ошибки.

Comment: Если `ArrayList<Ticker> data` заменить на `Map<String, Ticker> data`, то десериализатор не нужен.

Comment: Да, хороший вариант.